# How to fix the webpage problem with IdentityServer4.AspNetIdentity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, identityserver4, asp.net-core-2.2

When I'm using IdentityServer4.AspNetIdentity. I used Individual User settings to create my project with Visual Studio 2019. And it can't open my website with the code 500

I searched Google but there's no result

My code in Startup.cs:

```
 services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseInMemoryDatabase("AuthDb"));

services.AddIdentity<SimpleUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
    .AddInMemoryPersistedGrants()
                    .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Resources.GetIdentityResources())
    .AddInMemoryApiResources(Resources.GetApiResources())
    .AddInMemoryClients(Clients.Get())
    .AddAspNetIdentity<SimpleUser>()
    .AddDeveloperSigningCredential();

            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
```

Error code:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]' has been registered.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorPagePropertyActivator.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<CreateActivateInfo>b__1(ViewContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.PropertyActivator`1.Activate(Object instance, TContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorPagePropertyActivator.Activate(Object page, ViewContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPageActivator.Activate(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageCoreAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context, Boolean invokeViewStarts)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderAsync(ViewContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.PartialTagHelper.RenderPartialViewAsync(TextWriter writer, Object model, IView view)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.PartialTagHelper.ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperRunner.RunAsync(TagHelperExecutionContext executionContext)
   at AspNetCore.Views_Shared__Layout.<ExecuteAsync>b__45_1()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperExecutionContext.SetOutputContentAsync()
   at AspNetCore.Views_Shared__Layout.ExecuteAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageCoreAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context, Boolean invokeViewStarts)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderLayoutAsync(ViewContext context, ViewBufferTextWriter bodyWriter)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderAsync(ViewContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, String contentType, Nullable`1 statusCode)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext actionContext, IView view, ViewDataDictionary viewData, ITempDataDictionary tempData, String contentType, Nullable`1 statusCode)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, ViewResult result)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultAsync(IActionResult result)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResultFilterAsync[TFilter,TFilterAsync]()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context, IEndpointRouter router, IUserSession session, IEventService events) in C:\local\identity\server4\IdentityServer4\src\IdentityServer4\src\Hosting\IdentityServerMiddleware.cs:line 72
   at IdentityServer4.Hosting.MutualTlsTokenEndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context, IAuthenticationSchemeProvider schemes) in C:\local\identity\server4\IdentityServer4\src\IdentityServer4\src\Hosting\MtlsTokenEndpointMiddleware.cs:line 60
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at IdentityServer4.Hosting.BaseUrlMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) in C:\local\identity\server4\IdentityServer4\src\IdentityServer4\src\Hosting\BaseUrlMiddleware.cs:line 36
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.MigrationsEndPointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

These are my full error message when I'm running my project. It can't open even my homepage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/7856

Make sure that in Views\Shared_LoginPartial.cshtml is

```
@inject SignInManager<SimpleUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<SimpleUser> UserManager
```

and not

```
@inject SignInManager<IdentityUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<IdentityUser> UserManager
```